# How can I multiply a vector with a matrix without numpy in Python

Tags: python, vector, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply a matrix with a vector but I can't find a way to make a vector without using NumPy
I need to find a way to create a vector without numpy so I can multiply it with a matrix

I tried an answer I have found here but it doesn't seem to work when I try to use it.It doesn't do anything when I run it no errors no response nothing
I just run it and nothing happens

Here is the code that I found from an answer here

```
def multiply(v, G):
result = []
for i in range(len(G[0])): #this loops through columns of the matrix
    total = 0
    for j in range(len(v)): #this loops through vector coordinates & rows of matrix
        total += v[j] * G[j][i]
    result.append(total)
return result
```

All this is coded in jupyter notebook

Comment: If you're not using NumPy, what structure are you containing your values in?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A list object can work as vector.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have no idea what the actual question is from reading this

Comment: Explain "doesn't seem to work". What happens, what should happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class noNumpy:
    def multiply(self,v,G):
        rMatrix = len(G[0]) #This gives us the number of elements inside a row of matrix.
        rVector = len(v) #This gives us the number of elements in vector
        nMatrix = len(G) #This gives us the number of rows of the matrix.
        totalList = []

        for i in (range(rVector)):
            for j in range(nMatrix):
                for k in range(rMatrix):
                    totalList.append(v[i]*G[j][k])

        print(totalList)

Matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]
vector = [1,2,3]
n1 = noNumpy()
n1.multiply(vector,Matrix)
```

This is the sample code that is not using NumPy. However, note that Python itself is a slow language plus using three loops is also not feasible but for small lists I suppose it must be fine.

I would appreciate any feedbacks and any better of doing this as well.

Comment: Thank you very much and I have to agree that this only works for small lists scenarios